# Rotation in a Vector2d class in Java

Tags: java, vector, rotation

I've been working on this for one hour, just can't get it.

I have a Vector2d class:

```
public class Vector2d
{
    public double x = 0.0;
    public double y = 0.0;

    ....
}
```

This vector class has a rotate() method which is causing me trouble.

The first snippet seems to make the x and y values smaller and smaller. The second one works just fine! Am I missing something simple here?

```
public void rotate(double n)
{
    this.x = (this.x * Math.cos(n)) - (this.y * Math.sin(n));
    this.y = (this.x * Math.sin(n)) + (this.y * Math.cos(n));
}
```

This works:

```
public void rotate(double n)
{
    double rx = (this.x * Math.cos(n)) - (this.y * Math.sin(n));
    double ry = (this.x * Math.sin(n)) + (this.y * Math.cos(n));
    x = rx;
    y = ry;
}
```

I just can't spot any difference there

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first line sets the value of `this.x` which is then used in the second line when what you really want is the original value of `this.x`. The second version works fine because you don't alter `this.x`.

Comment: Oh no, can't believe I missed that. I feel so stupid. Thank you!