# Java How to make a graphics object move in its facing direction

Tags: java, animation, math, awt, trigonometry

Over the past few weeks I’ve been trying to fix a trigonometry issue I have. I need to make a Java.awt Graphics image that I drew with an input x and y from a USB joystick move in the direction it's currently facing, I got the rotating but I need to find out how to make the `moveForward()` function.

A little more background is that currently I want to use the joystick **x axis** to turn the image. I tried using `x = speed * sin(angle)` and `y = speed * cos(angle)`. The joystick is also made by Logitech, and I’m trying to make an FRC (First Robotics Competition) robot Simulator.

Essentially The image below shows what I have in mind. I want **the robot to move up, down, turn left and right**, and **at any given rotation it can move towards that rotation**.

[image: Ideal Image Function]

If anyone could help that would be amazing.

Please note...again I am doing this **in Java** and I've been trying to fix this for 2 weeks.

> If more code is needed please comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general approach for these kinds for problems is to use a *direction vector*. This vector is used to keep track of the heading of your object.

To rotate the object: Just [rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5207708/rotation-in-a-vector2d-class-in-java) the vector using the new angle.

To move the object: multiply the vector with the current speed (which can be constant). Finally add the vector to your object's position to get the new position. Like this:

`newPosition = direction.multiply(speed).add(position)`

Then draw the object at the new position and rotation.

---

Side note:

Multiplying a vector with a scalar is just `v.x*scalar` and `v.y*scalar`. Adding is just `v.x+a and`v.y+b`. So:

```
newPosition.x = direction.x * speed + position.x;
newPosision.y = direction.y * speed + position.y;
```

Comment: Sounds like it would work, but how do i use Vectors? I’ve never used them before Ive always used arrays.

Comment: Vector math is not hard, but the win is that it's easier to reason about and you don't have to mess with complex trigonometry. Just keep track of the direction vector. Check out [these](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/111799/movement-with-vector-math) [questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/85765/beginner-how-do-i-calculate-a-vector) for some examples

Comment: Thank you, I got an idea of what to do with the vector, I should have it might work.